# Error in Function b()

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I was trying to make a simple calculator in javascript. However, the code doesn't seem to work. The function a(), clr() are working properly while the functions **b() and res() are not working**. Can Anyone help me with the same?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        var num1, cal;
        function a(x) {
            document.f.num.value += x;
        }
        function b(x) {
            num1 = parseInt(document.f.num.value);
            document.f.num.value = "";
            cal = x;
        }
        function clr() {
            num1 = null;
            cal = null;
            document.f.num.value = "";
        }
        function res() {
            switch (cal) {
                case '+':
                    document.f.num.value = num1 + parseInt(document.f.num.value);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    document.f.num.value = num1 - parseInt(document.f.num.value);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    document.f.num.value = num1 * parseInt(document.f.num.value);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    document.f.num.value = num1 / parseInt(document.f.num.value);
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        input[type="button"] {
            width:35px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="f">
        <input type="text" name="num" value="">
        <br>
        <input type="button" name="7" value="7" onclick="a(7)">
        <input type="button" name="8" value="8" onclick="a(8)">
        <input type="button" name="9" value="9" onclick="a(9)">
        <input type="button" name="+" value="+" onclick="b(+)">
        <br>
        <input type="button" name="4" value="4" onclick="a(4)">
        <input type="button" name="5" value="5" onclick="a(5)">
        <input type="button" name="6" value="6" onclick="a(6)">
        <input type="button" name="-" value="-" onclick="b(-)">
        <br>
        <input type="button" name="1" value="1" onclick="a(1)">
        <input type="button" name="2" value="2" onclick="a(2)">
        <input type="button" name="3" value="3" onclick="a(3)">
        <input type="button" name="*" value="*" onclick="b(*)">
        <br>
        <input type="button" name="0" value="0" onclick="a(0)">
        <input type="button" name="C" value="C" onclick="clr(C)">
        <input type="button" name="=" value="=" onclick="res(=)">
        <input type="button" name="/" value="/" onclick="b(/)">
        <br>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Define *"not working"*

Comment: Please check the JavaScript console and post error messages here (if any). If you don't know what the JavaScript console is, you can ignore my comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the operation as a string, e.g.:

```
<input type="button" name="-" value="-" onclick="b('-')">
```

i.e. the onclick handler becomes `b('-')` not `b(-)`

Comment: Oh that was a really foolish error. The res() function is still not working. :(

Comment: Did you put the `=` in quotes too?